# Smooth Scroll to hash without bloated plugin3

Tags: jquery

I've looked at all the other questions and can't figure out what I have wrong. This function is supposed to scroll to hash onClick.

```
$('.scrolltohash').click(function(e) {  

    //alert('We Got Here');

    var scrolltothis = $(this).attr('href');
    var $scrolltothis = $(scrolltothis);

    //alert($scrolltothis);

    var position = $scrolltothis.offset().top;

    //alert(position);

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: position
    }, 2000);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I get the following error

TypeError: $scrolltothis.offset(...) is undefined

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/853jozk4/3/

Comment: It should say position, but it's not actually getting that far in the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing with the ID `sticky-header` in your example. The offset of nothing is `undefined`.

Comment: You're correct, they should add `id="sticky-header"` to the current element with `calss="sticky-header"`

Comment: Wow, I looked at this for like an hour.  Sometimes it takes someone else to point out the obvious.